# java interfaces and parameters types

Tags: java, interface, parameterized

I'm trying to parameterize a generic type with an interface and Eclipse tells me that method `abc()` is not implemented for the type `T`. Of course it is not implemented since `T` is an interface, the program will figure out at runtime what `T` really is. So, if anyone could help me solve this, I would be really appreciate.

I have something like:

```
interface myInterface {
    String abc();
}

class myClass<T> implements myClassInterface<T> {
    String myMethod() {
        T myType;
        return myType.abc();   // here it says that abc() is not implemented for the type T
    }
}

public class Main{
      public static void Main(String[] arg) {
         myClassInterface<myInterface> something = new myClass<myInterface>;
      }
}
```

Comment: where is myClassInterface defined?

Comment: T is a generic type. Where's the connection to your interface?

Comment: [Bounded generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have defined it `T` is of type `Object`. What you want instead is giving the compiler the hint that `T` is actually a type of `myInterface`. You do that by defining that `T` extends `myInterface`:

```
class myClass<T> implements myClassInterface<T extends myInterface>{
       String myMethod(){
            T myType;
            return myType.abc();
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried:  class myClass<T extends myInterface> implements myClassInterface<T>    and it worked. Thank you !